# Master HTML inside a node using multilingual text

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm using Drupal 7 .. Here is my issue :

I would like to

1. .. using a node to type HTML inside the body ... in which i include nodes bodies for eg

Body :

```
<p>[nid:6:body]</p>
```

So first of all how do we do that ?

And is it possible to use the t() function instead ? Like inside the BODY field of the node

```
<p>t("Text whatever blabla")</p>
```

So I can translate the content automatically ?

2. this HTML should be in a node that is translated to different languages but i would like to have a master node that if i change it .. it changed all the translated nodes ... like for eg i change the

   above by a < div > and this has to be changed automatically in all the translated nodes... how is that possible ?

Comment: what module are you using to accomplish the `<p>[nid:6:body]</p>` feature?

Comment: that's what i'm asking for ... how can i do this?